# Testing internal functions in Mocha ESlint error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, eslint

I'm currently developing an Nodejs application and carrying out some unit tests (I'm using Mocha, Chai and Sinon).

I ran into a little ESlint error when I exported and tested an internal function.

```
function _buildPayload(){
    //....
}

module.exports = { _buildPayload };
```

Then in my test script

```
const {_buildPayload} = requires('./someModule')

describe('Test',function(){
          it('Should work',function(){
              let expected = _buildPayload();
             })
        })
```

When I write the `let expected = _buildPayload();` ESlint returns the following error:

```
error  Shouldn't be accessing private attribute '_buildPayLoad'
```

My question is should I change the name of my function to not represent and internal even though it is?

Comment: If you're exporting it for the sole purpose of testing it, you might consider not testing it directly and simply testing the functions that use it (ones that _are_ exported). If it's not being exercised through those other exported methods, then that might hint at it being redundant. There's plenty of discussion about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@philipisapain makes a good point that testing internal methods may not be necessary. If you do need to do it, you have a couple options:

1. Disable the rule by placing `/* eslint-disable rule-name */` at the top of any test scripts that call private methods.
2. Disable the rule in all test scripts using a [glob config](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns) in your `.eslintrc`, provided you're using at least ESLint `v4.1.0`:

   ```
   "overrides": [{
       "files": ["*.test.js"],
       "rules": [{
           "rule-name": "off"
       }]
   }]
   ```